# Cannot Serve International Characters From Lisp Portable AllegroServe

Tags: localization, internationalization, lisp, common-lisp, httpserver

I am using Clozure Cl on Mac os x 10.9 and Portable allegro serve
I have a file with text has characters like **ı ç ş ö** (these are some characters Turkish also have) and **some Arabic characters**. I cannot serve them. when i visit from the browser this kind of characters are not displayed at all, only part of text showed is the ones until the first **ı** in the text.

In Lisp i use a function composed with a `do` and `read-line`s and `format` (or i have tried `print` `princ` `prin1` also) reads entire document and when i set the `:external-format :utf-8` it shows the read characters properly in Lisp. Problem is in serving them, if i can serve them as i read on Lisp it will be done.

Also If do not set `:external-format`at all, in Lisp it is read improperly, as expected, however, this time the browser can show all the text but with wrong characters in place of above described characters.

How to fix that and use `external-format`s character encodings properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.xach.com/lisp/allegro-cl/2001-3/964.html for an example on how to use :external-format in AllegroServe.

Cheers
  Frank

P.S. I also posted an answer to the same question newsgroup comp.lang.lisp .